# Verificar se campo é igual a zero na base de dados

Tags: php

Como se faz uma *query* que verifica na base de dados se um campo é igual a zero (em PHP OOP)?

Comment: Te aconselho a colocar pelo menos o que tentou fazer para que alguém te ajude.

Comment: Poste o código que já elaborou ou de mais detalhes do seu problema. Um select * from tabela where campo = 0, resolve.

Answer (score 2):

Tente a seguinte query:

```
SELECT campos FROM tabela WHERE campo = 0 -- Caso o campo seja numérico

SELECT campos FROM tabela WHERE campo LIKE '0' -- Caso o campo seja varchar
```

Para referenciar no PHP, você precisará fazer todo o "ritual":

```
<?php
// Cria a conexão
$host  = 'localhost'; // Endereço do servidor
$banco = 'meu_banco'; // Nome do banco de dados
$login = 'meu_login'; // Login no banco de dados
$senha = 'e_a_senha'; // Senha do banco de dados
$query = 'SELECT campos FROM tabela WHERE campo = 0';

try {
    // Conecta ao banco
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$banco, $login, $senha);

    // Prepara a consulta
    $consulta = $pdo->prepare($query);
    // Executa a consulta no banco
    $consulta->execute();
    // Faça o que for necessário com os dados
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    exit('Erro ao carregar o banco de dados.');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta fazer assim, um IF.

```
$sql = "select * from tabela where campo = 'sua variavel';
$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
$record = $sth->fetch();
if ($sth->fetchColumn() > 0){
 //faz isso
}
else{
   faz isso...
}
```